# Does it make sense to create a raid array with SSD's?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

We had a big problem in our local network at the school, many people were not able to login to their virtual machines.

After a week our teachers found out that the problem was because of the raid array with SSD harddisks.

There were too many I/O's in the queue, normally there shouldn't be more than one I/O. They measured it with a tool called "perfmon" (not the one which is included in windows).

Why are SSD's so slow in this case?

Comment: You're asking two different question. Do you want to know the cause of that problem or whether making a RAID array out of SSDs makes sense?

Comment: I want to know both.

Comment: Oh sure, the concept of queues was introduced because there should always be only one request in it. Thanks for reminding me of that. -- Sorry for the irony. I think it's obvious that this question cannot be answered and that the teachers involved need to go back to step one, namely analyse the root cause (and this time for real). -- And BTW, that must be a rich school... or there can't be many students... which makes the whole case even more suspicious.

Comment: This information is from my teacher.

Comment: There are about 150 computers in the network as far as i know.

Comment: Either way. HDDs are good enough for Google so why wouldn't they be good enough for 150 users. Especially if one is going for a RAID anyway, because then why not have a RAID 0 for additional speed, resulting e.g. in a RAID 10. In my view, the setup alone suggests that any technical info should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: It is pronounced "RAID one zero" not "RAID ten"